# How can I convert the values in one column into headers of a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns, "Partnumber", "Specifications" and "Value", I need to create a table with all data as VARCHAR in which each value in the column "Specifications" appears as Header.

I tried to use PIVOT but I didn't understand it very well (I'm a newbie); I'm using SQLServer.

These are the first rows in the original table:

```
Partnumber|Specifications|Value|
181504825 |Rotation      |CW   |
1541      |Belt Width (_)|7/16 |
156938    |Depth (mm)    |73   |
1522231   |Grooves       |6    |
1522236   |Grooves       |4    |
1522348   |Grooves       |4    |
1541      |Grooves       |1    |
181504825 |Height (mm)   |107.95|
156938    |Inlet (mm)    |11.5 |
```

I need to create a new table like this:

```
Partnumber|Belt Width (_)|Depth (mm)|Grooves |Height (mm)|Inlet (mm)|Rotation|
1522231   |              |          |6       |           |          |        |
1522236   |              |          |4       |           |          |        |
1522348   |              |          |4       |           |          |        |
1541      |7/16          |          |1       |           |          |        |
156938    |              |73        |        |           |11.5      |        |
181504825 |              |          |        |107.95     |          |CW      |
```

Each Partnumber and the headers must appear without duplicates and in order, some Partnumber can appear without information and I can delete the row later.
I would like to mention that the column "Specifications" contains 981 headers after deleting duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select Partnumber, max(case when Specifications='Rotation' then value end) as Rotation,
max(case when Specifications='Belt Width (_)|' then value end) as BeltWidth (_)|,
max(case when Specifications='Depth (mm)' then value end) as Depthmm,
max(case when Specifications='Grooves' then value end) as Grooves,
max(case when Specifications='Height (mm)' then value end) as Height,
max(case when Specifications='Inlet (mm)' then value end) as Inlet,
max(case when Specifications='Belt Width (_)' then value end) as belt
from table_name group by Partnumber
```

Comment: Thank you!, this solution works great with my issue, I just don't know how to do it quickly for the 981 unique values in "Specificactions" but I'll be able to have a better start with the answer you've provided me!